# Debugging key event flow in OS X before it reaches an app

Tags: macos, keyboard, dtrace

I have a user who reports that a particular keystroke isn't working `(control-apostrophe)` in my app on OS X. This does work for him on other machines.

I added some logging and my app never receives the `NSEvent` for the keyDown. 
Disabling universal access for assistive devices didn't fix it either. 
Nothing in keyboard shortcuts in system preferences uses that shortcut. 
Is there any way to trace a keystroke's path through the OS to find out why my app doesn't get it? Is this something dtrace can do?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but for anyone needing to do this I'll give an answer. I'm not going to go through the usual ways of tracking down a kb shortcut that is going bad, but you will have to make sure you do not have it set in system services, keyboard maestro, quicksilver and all of those apps that allow kb customization. Check this first. If you don't have a lot of kb shortcuts set through sys preferences, you might want to consider just deleting your plist file and letting the system default back to a fresh state. search for com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist and delete this. If this doesn't solve your issue or you don't want to delete the plist then run dtrace's iosnoop command from terminal. This will just dump everything going on. Hit the key and ⌃ c to stop the output and inspect the output. You could output this to a text file and do some grep magic on it, but this should be enough to head in the right direction.